# rails: sqlite3 no such column error when adding partial unique index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

rails version 5.1.3, ruby version 2.4.1, sqlite version on my desktop is 3.11.0, gem sqlite3 version is 1.3.13.

in `schema.rb` I have

```
  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "question_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.boolean "judge_choice", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["question_id", "user_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id_and_user_id", unique: true
    t.index ["question_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_answers_on_user_id"
  end
```

in migration file I tried to `add_index` like this `add_index :answers, [:question_id, :judge_choice], unique: true, where: "judge_choice is true"`

it doesn't matter if it's `is true` or `IS TRUE`, etc. when hit `rails db:migrate` sqlite3 kept complaining

> "No such column: true"

if changed to `where: "judge_choice"` then it will successfully migrate but the unique index just won't work. I can add as many answers with the same `question_id` and `judge_choice:true` as I want in console.

My intention: what I was trying to do was adding database level uniqueness to make sure there was only one answer whose `judge_choice` was true for each question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by migrating from sqlite3 to postgresql. `where: "judge_choice is true"` didn't give me trouble in `pg`. the partial unique index is working. maybe it can be solved in sqlite3, so I'm still willing to hear other voices.